# Nature trip in Germany

Tags: germany, nature-and-wildlife, trekking, parks-and-gardens

I am planning a trip to Germany for the end of September, any good place where to go?
In particular, I would like to see some nice lakes.

Comment: Is there any particular part of the country that you are interested in (e.g., the northern part, the Rhine Valley, or Bavaria? Right now, your question is a bit broad.

Answer (score 3):

Do you already have other destinations in mind, or is it just trekking and lakes? On foot, by bike, by boat? Genuine nature or scenery with tourist infrastructure?

There are many lakes, but keep in mind that Germany is densely populated, you won't find really spectacular wilderness. Have a look at these examples:

- [Alpsee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpsee)
- [Spreewald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreewald)
- [Mecklenburgische Seenplatte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecklenburg_Lake_District)
- [Bodensee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Constance)